Permission error with Arch Linux and Laravel
I'm creating a Laravel project, and I'm struggling with permissions. When I first create the project through a terminal command, I have to change the root folder permission to 777 because I can't modify the files. I know that giving a permission of 777 is not secure, but that was the only solution that worked for me initially.
However, this is only a temporary solution. Whenever I create a new file from the terminal (for example, a controller with an artisan command), I can't modify it without first changing its permission to 777. This is very cumbersome. Interestingly, if I create the file manually, it works as expected.
How can I solve this issue? I want to use artisan commands without having to change the permissions every time. I'm using Arch Linux (I'm a newbie) and PhpStorm.
